# How do I include select2 in quick edit and bulk edit wordpress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-select2, custom-post-type

I have a custom quick edit field in a custom post type

I have used the following code for adding the field and its options in the functions.php file.

```
echo '<label class="alignleft">
  <span class="title">Production Member</span>
  <select name="production_mem_select" id="production_mem_select" style="width:99%;max-width:25em;">
         <option class="production-option" value="0">None</option>';

        $users = get_users( array( 'fields' => array( 'ID' ) ) );
        foreach ($users as $user) {
          
          $usermeta = get_user_meta ( $user->ID);
          
          $username = $usermeta['first_name'][0] . " " . $usermeta['last_name'][0];
          if(isset($username)){
            $username = get_userdata($user->ID)->user_login;
          }
            echo "<option class='production-option' value='{$user->ID}'>{$username}</option>\n";
        }
  
  echo '</select>';
```

[image]

As soon as I initialize select2 with

```
jQuery(function($){
      $( document ).ready(function(){
       $('#production_mem_select').select2();
      });
  });
```

or

```
jQuery(function($){
       $('#production_mem_select').select2();
  });
```

the dropdown becomes unclickable.

However, I found a snippet here (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/147876/replacing-select2-in-admin-backend-for-all-selects) which helped me in making the dropdown inside the quick edit select2. I am pasting the code:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(
function( $ ) {
    $( "select:visible" ).select2(); // Only fire on visible inputs to begin with.
    $( document.body ).on( "focus", ".ptitle,select",
        function ( ev ) {
            if ( ev.target.nodeName === "SELECT" ) {
                // Fire for this element only
                $( this ).select2({ width: "element" });
            } else {
                // Fire again, but only for selects that haven't yet been select2'd
                $( "select:visible" ).not( ".select2-offscreen" ).select2({
                    width: "element"
                });
            }
        }
    );
}
```

);

But the issue here is that the default dropdown toggle is broken because of this code. i.e. when I do a mousedown (keep the left mouse button pressed down) then the dropdown options show and I am able to search but as soon as I let go of the mousedown (release the left mouse button) the dropdown menu disappears.

My main aim is that I want a dropdown field in the quick edit section where I can search for users and then save the data in a custom field. I have created the custom field and everything is working fine. I just want the option to assign a user in the quick edit section as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a boilerplate to replicate my setup:

```php
<?php

add_action('quick_edit_custom_box',  'misha_quick_edit_fields', 10, 2);
    
function misha_quick_edit_fields( $column_name, $post_type ) {

      echo '</div></div></fieldset>';
      
      echo '<fieldset class="inline-edit-col-right">
      <div class="inline-edit-col">
      <div class="inline-edit-group wp-clearfix">';
      
      echo '<label class="alignleft">
      <span class="title">QA Member</span>
      <span class="input-text-wrap"><select name="qa_member" multiple="multiple" id="qa_member_quick_edit">
      <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
      </select></span>
      </label>';
      ?>
          <script>
          jQuery(function($){
            $( document ).ready(function(){
             $('#production_mem_select').select2();
            });
        });
          </script>
      <?php

}


function enqueue_select2_jquery() {
  if ( 'edit.php' != $pagehook ) {
        return;
    }
 
    wp_enqueue_style('select2', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script('select2', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js');
    // please create also an empty JS file in your theme directory and include it too
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_select2_jquery' );
```

Comment: From reading what I understand is that whenever you are using select2 package, native dropdown fields are broken, and you want to prevent that ?

Comment: No I want that custom field to be a searchable select field but and the only way I know is to use select2 for such thing.

`jQuery(function($){
       $('#production_mem_select').select2();
  });`

This code makes it unclickable and the code I found on a different question makes the select2 work but when I click on the select it doesn't stay open to search and select instead automatically closes.

The select I want to convert to select2 is hidden inside the quick edit form and it is becoming a pain to make it searchable @Bhanu

Comment: ISHAN, edit your question and add the complete php code so that someone can reproduce it locally.

Comment: There you go I have added a boilerplate code for you and other. Thank you